# Getting CancelledError when using Python asyncio to stream audio into Dialogflow streaming_detect_intent()

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to write a custom Dialogflow integration. I am starting by writing a small program that streams audio to Dialogflow's streaming_detect_intent(). I have modified existing examples. For the audio, I am using sounddevice.

I have two Python tasks. One gets the audio, the other handles Dialogflow. The tasks communicate through a shared queue.  My code fails when I stream audio into Dialogflow. The immediate culprit is an asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError(). The trace is

File "/home/andrew/experiments/messaging/a_recording.py", line 95, in sample_streaming_detect_intent
async for response in stream:
File "/home/andrew/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers_async.py", line 102, in _wrapped_aiter
async for response in self._call: # pragma: no branch
File "/home/andrew/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py", line 327, in _fetch_stream_responses
await self._raise_for_status()
File "/home/andrew/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/aio/_call.py", line 233, in _raise_for_status
raise asyncio.CancelledError()
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

The Dialogflow task

```
async def sample_streaming_detect_intent(
    loop, audio_queue, project_id, session_id, sample_rate
):

    client = dialogflow.SessionsAsyncClient()

    audio_config = dialogflow.InputAudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=dialogflow.AudioEncoding.AUDIO_ENCODING_LINEAR_16,
        language_code="en",
        sample_rate_hertz=sample_rate,
    )

    async def request_generator(loop, project_id, session_id, audio_config, audio_queue):

        query_input = dialogflow.QueryInput(audio_config=audio_config)

        # Initialize request argument(s)
        yield dialogflow.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(
            session=client.session_path(project_id, session_id), query_input=query_input
        )

        while True:
            chunk = await audio_queue.get()
            if not chunk:
                break
            # The later requests contains audio data.
            yield dialogflow.StreamingDetectIntentRequest(input_audio=chunk)

    # Make the request
    client_task = asyncio.create_task(
        client.streaming_detect_intent(
            requests=request_generator(
                loop, project_id, session_id, audio_config, audio_queue
            )
        )
    )

    try:
        stream = await client_task
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"failed with {e.__cause__}")

    try:
        async for response in stream:
            print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"failed with {e.__cause__}")

    query_result = response.query_result

    print("=" * 20)
    print("Query text: {}".format(query_result.query_text))
    print(
        "Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n".format(
            query_result.intent.display_name, query_result.intent_detection_confidence
        )
    )
    print("Fulfillment text: {}\n".format(query_result.fulfillment_text))
```

some of the calling code

```
    audio_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    # to assert that we are using the same event loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    await asyncio.gather(
        record_audio(fp, loop, audio_queue, sample_rate, device, channels),
        sample_streaming_detect_intent(
            loop, audio_queue, project_id, session_id, sample_rate
        ),
    )
```

Since tasks communicate via a queue, I tried the following: 1. I connected a task that wrote the streaming audio into a file. 2. I wrote a task that read said audio stored in a file, and sent it to the Dialogflow task. 3. I had asserts to make sure the same event_loop was used. 4. In my read_audio() task, I used loop.call_soon_threadsafe

Using a debugger and looking at the trace, the problems seem to be coming from GRPC. I checked to see if the audio settings were correct (also it tends to throw a meaningful exception). I've tried to read up as much as I can on CancelledError().

Comment: I found the problems. There are two. The first problem is in the callback. Sounddevice uses numpy arrays. Dialogflow expects bytes. So I changed indata.copy() to indata.tobytes(). The second problem is in InputStream(). We told Dialogflow we are using LINEAR_16 (PCM). However the bytes are probably being converted to float32. So we have to set InputStream's dtype to "int16"

Answer (score 0):

I found the problems. There are two. The first problem is in the callback. Sounddevice uses numpy arrays. Dialogflow expects bytes. So I changed indata.copy() to indata.tobytes(). The second problem is in InputStream(). We told Dialogflow we are using LINEAR_16 (PCM). However the bytes are probably being converted to float32. So I set InputStream's dtype to "int16